# Cross Domain Requests Not Working With SoundCloud in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, soundcloud

I simply cannot get a json response in Safari, calling SoundCloud's API.

```
var inputSet={url:setUrl},
    clientId={client_id:client_id};
$.getJSON( "https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json", $.extend(inputSet, clientId), function( data ) {
console.log(data);
});
```

This returns an Origin Access-Control error in Safari but not in Chrome. CORS is not working at all.

Saw [CORS not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802249/cors-not-working-at-all), implemented 'working' answer, exact same error, only Safari.

adding a callback parameter does not return that error, however returns the ajax error 
`"parsererror" SyntaxError {}` which I presume is due to the response still being json and not jsonp. This does not work in either browser.

As it stands I cannot get this cross domain request working in chrome, even though the docs

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#crossdomain

say I can.

Safari network tab:
[image: Safari]

Safari response:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://seam.li is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (17235000.json, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/17235000.json?client_id=CLIENT_ID. Origin https://seam.li is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (seam.li, line 0)
```

Linked page loads fine in browser.

Comment: What does the Network tab in Chrome show?

Comment: Not sure if you mean Safari, as Chrome is the one that works, but the api calls return 200, 302, or 304 on Chrome

Comment: Updated with image of Safari Network

Comment: Can you show the details (e.g. response)?

Comment: Updated with response

Comment: Can you show the response the browser received? I don't know about Safari, but it's in the Chrome tools.

Comment: I believe that's the photo I put up? One responded 200 and one just has a hypen

Answer (score 4):

Using the other URLs seems to work fine. The issue lies with `/resolve.json` where it uses a 302 Redirect to send you to the right API URL and it doesn't jive with Safari.

**According to the SoundCloud API Doc:**

> The resolve resource allows you to lookup and access API resources when you only know the SoundCloud.com URL.

If you don't need this functionality I suggest using the URL directly. Here's a working example.

```
$.getJSON("https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/17235000.json?client_id=CLIENT_ID", 
    function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Sadly I do need the resolve functionality. This relies on a user inputting the url to a SoundCloud set, and then the service plays it. I sadly can't reasonably ask them to input the api url of a playlist :(

Comment: You'll have to use a CORS proxy

Comment: Any advice on setting one up?

Comment: What you want to do is connect to a URL that you control, that way you can control the headers before it gets to JS. In your case, you'll want to capture the data after it does redirect. Let your server worry about it. I found this one on github: https://github.com/gr2m/CORS-Proxy

Comment: Indeed, though sadly the one you linked did not work. https://jsonp.jit.su/ worked for me, although I had to swap out a module due to a bug.

Proxy now sits at seam.li/json/

Comment: In case anyone else finds this answer and like me think it implies that `/resolve.json` doesn't support `jsonp`: it does. Just use jsonp instead of json and safari won't complain about the 302 redirect. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440040/soundcloud-api-origin-mysite-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: @AndreasHultgren Keep in mind that JSONP also has it's drawbacks.  Since JSONP is a JavaScript wrapper you can run into illegal character issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094214/invalid-javascript-jsonp-response-from-soundcloud-api