# Invalid javascript/JSONP response from Soundcloud API

Tags: api, google-chrome, jsonp, google-chrome-devtools, soundcloud

When I include [this url](https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/128149524.json?callback=__loadjsonp__3&client_id=9d5bbaf9df494a4c23475d9fde1f69b4) as a `<script>` in my HTML document, Chrome does not call my callback function, whereas it works perfectly for other urls returned by soundcloud's `resolve` api.

After a long investigation using Chrome Dev Tools, I finally found out that the javascript returned by that call fires a SyntaxError (cf the screenshot below).

[image]

How can I get my callback function to be called as usual for that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevTools actually pinpoint the issue:

[image: \u2029 character in JSON]

There is an unallowed character ([\u2028](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm)) in the response. SoundCloud messed up sanitizing that. This JSONP response is invalid in all browsers.

To work around it, you can simply fetch the JSON file directly. SoundCloud CORS setup seems [to allow that](http://jsbin.com/sowateneha/1/edit).

Comment: It does work with CORS, thank you! Nevertheless, do you know a way to make the CORS request from localhost (for development) ?